# How to set alias name for select statament

Tags: sql

```
(SELECT ........ 
 FROM ......... 
 WHERE.......
 ORDER BY ...
) AS My_select 
FROM table-name1 
INNER JOIN table-name2 
WHERE table-name1.column-name=table-name2.column-name;
```

Is it possible or not.I tried this way but not getting answer.Please tell me any one.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?
also hyphen (`-`) in table names may be dangerous without backticks `\`table-name1\``

Comment: @HerrSerker, double quotes is the ANSI SQL way for delimited identifiers, not backticks. (No dbms specified.)

Comment: Your syntax is all wrong. When INNER JOIN syntax an ON clause is required (you can also have a WHERE clause, but that's optional.)

Comment: @Durga prasad Please post your table structure or some form of example where others can understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery must have relation with your main query, if not you will get a message about "subquery returns more than one row" and it not works! ;-)

Comment: Or aggregate function, or FETCH FIRST 1 etc